# Импорт из XML файла в таблицу MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Приветствую!

Есть задачка по импорту ряда справочников формата DBF в MS SQL Server 2008 из приложения на C#. Ситуация осложняется тем, что я могу делать импорт данных только через хранимые процедуры на сервере, так как у самого приложения может не быть прав на прямую работу с таблицами, в которые нужно добавлять данные. Потому, например, `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy` не очень-то подходит, как и прямые запросы через `SqlCommand`. Сразу скажу, что есть ограничение и на команду `EXEC` на сервере, т.е. динамические запросы не взлетят.

Сейчас имеется порядка 12 файлов XML, в которых лежат сконвертированные из DBF данные, это — источник. В качестве приемника используются 12 таблиц в БД MS SQL.

При этом структуры таблиц-источников и таблиц-приемников не совпадают (типы, названия полей). Обусловлено это тем, что в XML данные хранятся без явного указания типа (*да, можно было бы делать схему в XSD но это не нужно, т.к. в оригинальных файлах, например, значения типа `int` сплошь и рядом хранятся в `char`, т.е. в источнике поле имеет тип `char`, в приемнике должно быть `int`*).

Имена полей не совпадают по причине того, что они просто криво были названы в DBF, и в MS SQL переносить это не хотелось (*например, название города в справочнике хранится в поле с названием I_GOR, в SQL БД - это же поле названо как Name*).

Зато вот число полей любой таблицы-источника совпадает с числом полей аналогичной таблицы-приемника.

Потому, решение видится в качестве *одной* хранимой процедуры, пусть 'sp_ImportXMLDictionary', которой бы на вход в качестве параметров подавались бы: имя таблицы, в которую нужно импортировать и XML-файл, который нужно импортировать. Процедура брала бы данные из каждой колонки XML, и просто бы вставляла в целевую таблицу в колонку с тем же порядковым номером.

**Пример:**

Изначально DBF содержит поля с данными:

```
COD_RS (char), GOR (char), I_GOR (char)
55             000         Нью-Васюки
56             002         Гадюкино
56             007         Васюки
```

То после обработки получаем на выходе следующий набор полей (c данными) в XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <SPRGOR>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <COD_RS>55</COD_RS>
    <GOR>000</GOR>
    <I_GOR>Нью Васюки</I_GOR>
  </SPRGOR>
  <SPRGOR>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <COD_RS>56</COD_RS>
    <GOR>002</GOR>
    <I_GOR>Гадюкино</I_GOR>
  </SPRGOR>
  <SPRGOR>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <COD_RS>56</COD_RS>
    <GOR>007</GOR>
    <I_GOR>Васюки</I_GOR>
  </SPRGOR>
</DocumentElement>
```

Целевая таблица имеет структуру:

```
ID (int, identity, PK), AreaCode (int), CityCode (int), Name (nvarchar(50))
```

В идеале хотелось бы сделать так, что бы первое поле из XML попадало в первое поле таблицы (ID ---> ID), второе из XML - в второе поле таблицы (COD_RS ---> AreaCode) и так далее, по числу полей. И да, с конвертацией данных при вставке в тип данных, указанных в приёмнике.

Ваше мнение, как лучше разрешить эту задачку? Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

Всё, что я видел пока, это вставка данных в таблицу либо с учетом структуры таблиц, либо предлагается использовать мастер для импорта (с маппингом полей и типов),  но использование мастеров не подходит изначально, а привязываться к структуре каждой из таблиц-источников и писать для каждой из них свою хранимку не очень хотелось бы (точнее, **очень не хотелось бы**).

*(Генерацию XML я уже сделал, проблема в последующей загрузке этих данных на сервер)*

Comment: 1. Я так понимаю, это разовая задача. Так что следует воспользоваться мастером импорта и не мучиться. 2. Что значит нет прав? Странно, что есть права на _создание_ (не _использование_) хранимок, но нет прав на использование обычных запросов. Дайте сами себе права и опять-таки не мучайтесь. 3. Иногда проще написать дюжину простых процедур, чем одну сложную. Написал - выполнил - выкинул.

Comment: Передавай XML строку в виде параметра в процедуру, а там читай её как XML, [см.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186918.aspx). Такое вроде было доступно с 2000-ого.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, 1. Нет, не разовая, а периодическая, раз в месяц. 2. Создавать хранимки я могу на тестовой БД, в продакшне все иначе, созданные хранимки в виде скрипта будут залиты DBA единожды. 3. Иногда - да, но не в этом конкретном случае, к сожалению (аналогичную процедуру впоследствии планируется использовать как минимум еще в нескольких местах).
@MaLS, спасибо, внутрь процедуры я таким образом передам XML, уже хорошо, потому как например, такое: `SET @xml = (
      SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (
        BULK 'D:\MyXMLData.xml', SINGLE_CLOB
      ) AS xml` дает ошибку 21(нет прав).

Comment: а) В целевой таблице `ID int identity`, и вы хотите вставлять _ID ---> ID_, для этого нужно будет включить `set identity_insert [TableName] on`, а на это нужны права. Будь я DBA, я бы такое не разрешил (в контексте задачи это кажется ненормальным). б) SqlBulkCopy я бы не сбрасывал со счетов (можно создавать временную таблицу, с помощью SqlBulkCopy импортировать в неё данные, а в процедуре из временной таблицы перекидывать данные в целевую). Впрочем, импорт из xml - тоже вполне годный вариант. в) Префикс `sp_` для процедур не рекомендуется использовать.

Comment: По пункту а) - на самом деле identity само не плохо генерится, вставлять вряд ли придется, в вопросе оставил это, т.к. что с ним делать и как - пока открытый вопрос. Вариант б) с временной таблицей кажется интересным, спасибо! А вот насчет импорта из XML - тут сложности с именованием колонок возникают, а точнее, при генерации таблицы из XML нужно знать имена тегов, в которые обрамлены данные, дабы использовать их при построении таблицы, например, вот тут, например: `SELECT t.c.value(''(ID/text())[1]'', ''INT'') as ID,.....` процедура должна знать, что в XML есть тэг ID типа `int`и это печалит.

Comment: `sp_` - так Stored Procedure же. На деле там двойной перфикс: `sp_sub_<ProcedureName>`, но если предложите альернативу, буду признателен. Спасибо за замечания! Перфикс - [sub] - код проекта. C таблицами так же: `tbl_sub_<TableName>`.

Comment: _"есть ограничение и на команду EXEC на сервере, т.е. динамические запросы не взлетят"_ это касается и динамических запросов внутри процедуры тоже? С использованием динамических запросов задача вроде бы решается (имена тэгов xml узнать можно, тип можно было бы посмотреть у столбца целевой таблицы). Но нужно учесть, будут ли данные импортироваться безусловно, или нужно ориентироваться на какой-то уникальный признак. Вопрос в том стоит ли идти таким путём.

Comment: Если динамический запрос будет сформирован внутри хранимки или передан в неё как текст, то он выполнится. Именно по этому пути и пошел сейчас, разбираюсь с тэгами XML и полями целевой таблицы. Данные будут импортироваться безусловно, т.е. все записи таблицы XML без фильтрации будут добавлены в целевую таблицу. В качестве признака (для работы уже с целевой таблицей) там есть отдельное GUID-поле, которое XML не затрагивает (нет этого значения там), оно будет передаваться как параметр хранимки и при импорте из XML будет подставляться наравне с данными из XML. Как-то так вот, думаю.

Comment: По префиксам: `sp_` - [ссылка 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd172115.aspx), [ссылка 2](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix), `tbl_` - [ссылка](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/154251/99746).

Comment: Спасибо за ссылочки! А по импорту в общем виде вижу ситуацию на данный момент так:
1. Получаем список имен полей и их типов из целевой таблицы в курсор.
2. Получаем имена тегов из XML через XQuery во второй курсор.
3. Фетчим курсор 2 и 1, и формируем текст запроса для выборки из XML.
4. Выполняем запрос, на выходе получая Table, которую уже инсёртим в целевую таблицу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот сдесь есть готовый пример кода, который не будет проблем подправить под даный случай:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672780/importing-xml-data-from-xml-file-to-sql-database

Comment: Да, спасибо, я именно похожим образом и сделал, через XPath. XML прокидывается как строка на сервер, и в хранимой процедуре уже распарсивается как таблица именно подобным образом. Принимаю ваш ответ, так как он наиболее соответствует реальности )